# VueAuthenticate - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I use Vue Authenticate (https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate) for VueJS 2.

I get an error when I click on login button, I can't find **login** in **this.$auth** :/

**Error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
>       at VueComponent.login (Login.vue?9314:70)
>       at Proxy.boundFn (vue.esm.js?efeb:187)
>       at click (Login.vue?8b9b:195)
>       at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:1937)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1772)

**Code:**

`<v-btn color="orange darken-1" flat @click.native="login()">Login</v-btn>`

**JS file store.js:**

```
methods: {
    login () {
      this.$auth.login(this.user).then(() => {
        alert('ok')
      }).catch(() => {
        alert('error')
      })
    }
  }
```

**VueJS Instance:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: Where are you registering the plugin? It should look like this `Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that $auth is undefined. Did you register the plugin with Vue.use like the documentation explains? Without registering the plugin, it won't be available on the Vue instance.